# Вывод пользовательского поля в 1С-Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Не выводится пользовательское поле из инфоблока. Пользовательское поле для компонента bitrix.news

В инфоблоке создал `UF_SEO_TOP`

В шаблоне компонента bitrix.news такой код

```
<? foreach ($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arSection): ?>
<li class="services__item gsap-element" data-hover-element>
<a href="<?= $arSection['SECTION_PAGE_URL'] ?>">
<div class="services__icon"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH? 
>/assets/images/icons/service-site.svg" alt="Иконка услуги"></div>
<div class="services__info">
<span class="services__info-name"><?= $arSection['NAME'] ?></span>
<p class="services__info-description"><? echo $arSection['DESCRIPTION']; ?></p>

<?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['UF_SEO_TOP']['VALUE']?>

</div>
</a>
</li>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Данные из пользовательского поля не выводятся. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Надо использовать не $arResult, а $arSection.